# How to avoid content "jumping" on AnimatedVisibility change?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When AnimatedVisibility state changes, the button appears and the next text jumps. How to make it move smoothly.

```
Row(
                verticalAlignment = CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(CenterVertically)
            ) {
                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visible = buttonBackEnabled,
                    enter = slideInHorizontally(initialOffsetX = { -it }),
                    exit = slideOutHorizontally(targetOffsetX = { -it })
                ) {
                    ButtonBack(
                        paddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp, 0.dp, 5.dp, 0.dp),
                        iconSize = 33.dp
                    ) {
                        mContext.findActivity()?.onBackPressed()
                    }
                }
                Text(
                    text = screenTitle,
                    fontSize = 19.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(CenterVertically)
                )
            }
```

Comment: Its probably because of boolean value that you have set in AnimatedVisibility. When its false-> the Text() covers button's position in a Row() and when its true, it gives space to button. Can you provide more code so that i can give detailed solution instantly?

Answer (score 1):

Although the animations are a bit different, using expand/shrink animations instead of slideIn/slideOout could be a good solutions for you because these animations achieve that the `Text` composable wouldn't jump but move smoothly.

So in this case you can try the following replacement:

- `slideInHorizontally(initialOffsetX = { -it })` -> `expandHorizontally()`
- `slideOutHorizontally(targetOffsetX = { -it })` -> `shrinkHorizontally()`